# Flagging a Directory to Avoid iCloud Backup

Tags: ios, icloud

My application's latest update recently got rejected as a single directory was too large for backup (36MB). This directory, `(/Documents/Templates/)`, does not need to be backed up to iCloud so I was curious as to how I would flag the directory to be avoided as backup occurred.

This is what I have, currently, that got rejected:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:finalURL];
    
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL

{
    
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *directory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    directory = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Templates"];
    
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:directory] == NO) {
        
        NSError *error;
        if ([fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:directory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error] == NO) {
            NSLog(@"Error: Unable to create directory: %@", error);
        }
        
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:directory];
        // exclude downloads from iCloud backup
        if ([url setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:&error] == NO) {
            NSLog(@"Error: Unable to exclude directory from backup: %@", error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the issue ? Your current code seems okay to me. Are you getting any errors or warnings ? Please explain

Comment: I'm not sure. I submitted about a week ago and they rejected it telling me I need to flag the directory. So I flagged the directory with he above code and they rejected it again.

Comment: Same reason ? Did you checked it on device ?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately.

Comment: Rejected due to same reason or any new reason ?